# how do I parse a varible do isolate a singular piece of data in python?

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

when I output the variable p using
`p[0]`
it outputs

```
<Ether  dst=4a:aa:ac:d6:57:00 src=99:c3:88:b0:56:2e type=IPv4 |<IP  version=4 ihl=5 tos=0x0 len=32 id=1 flags= frag=0 ttl=64 proto=icmp chksum=0x83e5 src=192.168.50.73 dst=1.2.3.4 |<ICMP  type=echo-request code=0 chksum=0x1026 id=0x0 seq=0x0 unused='' |<Raw  load='test' |>>>>
```

and I want to isolate the `test` in `<Raw  load='test'` but that wont always be the same string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the data by using:

```
p[0][Raw].load
```

The `[Raw]` accesses the `Raw` *layer*, and the `.load` accesses the `load` *field* (from the `Raw` *layer*).

Comment: Im really sorry but I don't have enough reputation points to upvote things yet but when I get 15 I will